# Accidentally changed a list to generator

Tags: python, list, generator

I am writing a Battleship game and I"m facing a few problems. I already wrote some lines of code enough to create a 10x10 map, random the location of a ship and give the player 10 turns to guess. Now I am trying to put numbers 1-10 in the top row and in the first column to make the map more clear.
Unfortunately it looks that after adding the numbers I changed my list to something different:

```
from random import randint

board = []

board.append((str(n) for n in(range(0, 11))))
liczba_kolumn = 10

for x in range(9):
    board.append([str(x + 1)] +["O"] * liczba_kolumn)

board.append(["10O"] + ["O"] * (liczba_kolumn - 1))

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))

print ("Let's play Battleship!")
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(1, len(board))

def random_col(board):
    return randint(1, len(board[0]))

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board) `
for turn in range(10):

    print ("Turn " + str(liczba_prob)) 
    guess_row = input("Guess Row:") 
    guess_col = input("Guess Col:")
    liczba_prob = liczba_prob - 1
    if guess_row == "" or guess_col == "":
        print ("guess the location")
    else:

        guess_row = int(guess_row) - 1
        guess_col = int(guess_col) - 1
        if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
            print ("Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!")
            break
        else:
            if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 9) or (guess_col < 0 or             guess_col > 9):
                print ("Wrong localisation")
            elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
                print ("You already guessed that one.")
```

First bug was

```
return randint(1, len(board[0]))
TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

I changed both random_functions from len() ones to just "11". But the next bug is

```
elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable.
```

My question is - in which moment did I change my board[] list to 'generator' and how do I turn it back into a list?

EDIT:

Thank you for your answers, they helped me a lot. Now I am trying to understand a different thing - why does the code

```
board = []
board.append(["10O"] + ["O"] * (10))
print(" ".join(board))
```

returns a bug : sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found ?
First and the next items are all in bracket. A code that looks pretty the same returns no bug:

```
board = []
board.append(["10O"] + ["O"] * 10)
def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))
print_board(board)
```

Comment: `(str(n) for n in range(0, 11))` is a generator. `[str(n) for n in range(0, 11)]` is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `board.append((str(n) for n in(range(0, 11))))` appends a generator to `board`. You probably want to `.extend()` or `.insert([str(n) ... ])` (watch the `[` and `]`)